# How to read image data sent from IOS in php?

Tags: php, ios, mysql

From the ios we are sending image using the following method.

```
 imageData=UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.3);
```

In the backend php code I am reading the data as

```
$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
   $contents = stream_get_contents($handle);
   fclose($handle);
```

I am trying to save the image data to mysql table from php. It is not working. Pls give a solution.

Comment: Encode it with base64 in iOS, decode it with base64 on the server.

Comment: Is there other way in php, if from ios side base64 encoding is not doing?

Comment: base64 works with android and ios.